# push array deep into document

Tags: php, mongodb, traversal

I have this document:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56db04fcf0aac2042ea63de4"),
"POST_ID" : 3,
"QA" : [
    {
        "Q_ID" : 1,
        "ANSWERS" : [ ]
    },
    {
        "Q_ID" : 2,
        "ANSWERS" : [ ]
    }
]
}
```

Now I want to push $answers into this document

```
    $answer = array('A_ID'=>$answer_id, 'ANSWER'=>$_POST['answer'], 'COMMENTS'=>array());
```

I tried this :

```
$collection->update(array('POST_ID'=>3),array('$push'=>array('QA.ANSWERS'=>$answer)),false,true);
```

which gives me error:

```
 Catchable fatal error: Argument 3 passed to MongoCollection::update() must be of the type array, boolean given, called in /var/www/html/ProjectTest/post.php on line 30 and defined in /var/www/html/ProjectTest/include/Function Helper.php on line 126
```

Is there a way i can do this?

Comment: error says third value must be array, you gave boolean false.

Comment: even when i remove the 3rd and 4th arguments it does not exactly pushes the answer into `ANSWERS`